# Angular, "title" & "alt" in <img> tag

Tags: angular, typescript, image, title, alt

i want to set `<img title="">` attributes for each image. But I want the `title` that the image itself has. How should I do it in code
this below is my code in .html

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{document.file}}" alt="img-alt" title="" class="img" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

````
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{document.file}}" [alt]="document.alt" [title]="document.title" class="img" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>```
````